# Hardware Planning for Open Nebula

Tags: linux, high-availability, opennebula

How do you plan Hardware allocation in terms of Physical servers to achieve a 100% or close HA. A 1 to 1 Pairing of Server Hardware using Heart Beat Corosync looks expensive. Is there a better way?