# How to achieve HA in open nebula?

Tags: high-availability, opennebula

I have just setup an open nebula environment for testing purpose and once everything will work well, will implement in production environment. But I have a doubt and not able to understand the HA thing in Open nebula.

Is there a way to achieve HA in open nabula without using 1:1 physical hardwares.

Any answer and suggestion highly appreciable !!!

Comment: Same question: https://serverfault.com/questions/907473/hardware-planning-for-open-nebula